# How to build web front end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this , I have couple of web services built using slim php framework which I have successfully integrated into a mobile app, I want to build a web interface for the same what are my best options ? I know I can use JavaScript for this but my main confusion is how to call these REST apis from front end and which framework to use .

Answer (score 2):

> I want to build a web interface for the same what are my best options ?

Your best options are depending on your overall requirements and setup. If you want to provide the same functionality in your Web Interface as in your mobile application use a sophisticated framework like AngularJS, BackboneJS, Ember, etc.

There are many out there. It is important to have a feeling of how those frameworks work and if those workflows are suiting your needs. For the start I would recommend to have a look at AngularJS.

> I know I can use JavaScript for this but my main confusion is how to call these REST apis from front end and which framework to use .

You can call your REST endpoints using plain Javascript or jQuery, if you don't use any framework. Here is an example with plain JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://example.org/api/...", true);
//register listener
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   ...
}
xhr.send();
```

Frameworks like AngularJS have pre built-in components to make calls to your REST API.

A pitfall could be that you have to enable CORS, depending on your setup. Make sure your server handles those requests appropriately. You have to set those Headers on the server side:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [YOUR_HTTP_DOMAIN_NAME]");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH");
```

But since your mobile applications are using your REST API, those calls on the web interface should be similar to your mobile calls.

Comment: No I don't want exact same functionality as my mobile app , there are many additional functions which aren't on mobile app neither I am making a responsive web app

Comment: To have good starting point use Twitter Bootstrap for your layout and go from there on. It seems like you need a Web Interface for administration, if so you have to make up your mind about authenticatio, additional functionality and so on. AngularJS is quite a mature framework to handle your requirements. Web frameworks and technologies are a world for itself.

Comment: Ok that makes sense , you are correct I am looking to build admin backend mainly which need not be responsive but when I looked at AJ2 it seems like a lot heavier on frameworks side than plain HTML CSS and Jquery isn't it ?

Comment: Yes if you are new to the world of web engineering, it can become quite intimidating. AngularJS uses plain JS under the hood and the same functionality can be achieved with plain JS. So does jQuery. As your application grows and complexity becomes higher the plain approach to just use HTML/CSS and plain JS can become a nightmare. Frameworks like AngularJS are offering a "safe"-path, because they can provide you a workflow for getting things done.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your REST web services from any web interface using jquery(http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or XR(https://www.npmjs.com/package/xr) or request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), etc.

Those links contains several examples.

Comment: Could you enlighten me where the frameworks like Angular JS etc come into play ?

Comment: AngularJs is a framework to build web pages. If you decide to use AngularJs then this come already with a $http package that allows you to use http request to you web services.